# sorting divs using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sorting

I'm trying to `sort divs` using `jQuery`, it does sort, but does not seems sorting properly.
[image]

This is after applying `sort`

here is `HTML` snippet.

```
<div class="container column">
    <div class="row">
        <section class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-3">
            <section class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1"><a href="./stafferLink/index.php" >Staffer Link</a></section>
            <section class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1"><a href="./stafferLink/view.php">View Data</a></section>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

and `jQuery`

```
var $divs = $(".container.column");

$(document).ready(function () {
    var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).find("a:first").text() > $(b).find("a:first").text();
    });
    $("#container").html(alphabeticallyOrderedDivs);
});
```

PS: `#container` is outermost `div` that contains all `divs` that need to be in order.

[Here it's](http://jsfiddle.net/gumfobs9/)

sorry, not `responsive`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9qmzgk55/3/ - can you recreate the case and share the link

Comment: im not a bootstrap user but isn't it supposed to be based on 12 col instead of 13 ? just a thought

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a casing issue try to sort your element ad ignore the case and using `localCompare` function.

> The localeCompare() method returns a number indicating whether a
>   reference string comes before or after or is the same as the given
>   string in sort order.

Code:

```
var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
    return $(a).find("a:first").text().toLowerCase().localeCompare($(b).find("a:first").text().toLowerCase());           
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bk66on10/

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

Comment: Thank you very much sir.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Really it's just about a proper function for sort. There's no sort for jQuery objects, it's basically using Array.prototype.sort. If you check on the documentation:

> If compareFunction is supplied, the array elements are sorted according to the return value of the compare function. If a and b are two elements being compared, then:
>
> If compareFunction(a, b) is less than 0, sort a to a lower index than b, i.e. a comes first.
>
> If compareFunction(a, b) returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different elements. Note: the ECMAscript standard does not guarantee this behaviour, and thus not all browsers (e.g. Mozilla versions dating back to at least 2003) respect this.
>
> If compareFunction(a, b) is greater than 0, sort b to a lower index than a.
> compareFunction(a, b) must always return the same value when given a specific pair of elements a and b as its two arguments. If inconsistent results are returned then the sort order is undefined.

What you are doing is:

```
return $(a).find("a:first").text() > $(b).find("a:first").text();
```

Which depending on how sort does the comparison, true or false values could be casted to 1 or 0 but never -1.

There's an example on the MDN on how to work with it:

```
  var items = [
  { name: 'Edward', value: 21 },
  { name: 'Sharpe', value: 37 },
  { name: 'And', value: 45 },
  { name: 'The', value: -12 },
  { name: 'Magnetic' },
  { name: 'Zeros', value: 37 }
];
items.sort(function (a, b) {
  if (a.name > b.name) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (a.name < b.name) {
    return -1;
  }
  // a must be equal to b
  return 0;
});
```

Visit the MDN page on Array.prototype.sort:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort