# Sorting HTML table by row data using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

**Question**

Given the following `HTML` table

```
<table id="sort-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>text*1234</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>text*1224</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>text*1254</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>texta*1234</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>textabc*1234</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>textab*1234</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>*2234</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>textabcd*1234</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>text*1234</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>textabc*1234*1234</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there a way to sort the rows inside of the `'sort-table'` table by the value of the first `<td>` element in each `<tr>` element? Sorting should be Alphabetical by each `'text'` first, and then numeric by the value after the `*`.

`JQuery` is available, but answers composed of vanilla `Javascript` will be preferred.

**Attempted Solution**

Using the following Javascript I have attempted to achieve the elusive functionality.

```
//get the rows of the table and put them in a NodeList
var tableRows = $("#sort-table")[0].children[0].children;
//create an empty 'tbody' element to replace the old table contents with
var tBody = document.createElement("tbody");
//get the old tbody element to replace it with an empty tbody element
var oldBody = $("#sort-table")[0].children[0];
//get the NodeList as an array
var rowsArray = [].slice.call(tableRows, 1);

//sort the array
rowsArray.sort();

//replace the current table body with an empty one
oldBody.parentNode.replaceChild(tBody, oldBody);

//put each array element in the new table body
rowsArray.forEach(function(entry) {
    var tableRef = document.getElementById('sort-table').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

    // Insert a row in the table at the last row
    var newRow   = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);

    // Insert a cell in the row at index 0
    var newCell  = newRow.insertCell(0);

    newCell.appendChild(entry);
});
```

here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rrLfLnb9/1/) showing how this currently works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method to organise the rows in to the order required:

```
$('#sort-table tr').sort(function(a, b) {
    var aText = $(a).find('td:eq(0)').text();
    var bText = $(b).find('td:eq(0)').text();

    if (aText > bText)
        return 1;
    else if (aText < bText)
        return -1;
    return 0;
}).appendTo('#sort-table');
```

[**Updated example**](https://jsfiddle.net/rrLfLnb9/4/)

Comment: The sort function is kind of wrong, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31749051/sorting-divs-using-jquery/31749992#31749992

Comment: @MinusFour so the `.sort()` method may do some weird things with out-of-date browsers, but modern browsers are fine right? To be sure, nothing appears to be incorrect in the behavior of the input camparison function.

Comment: @LanguidSquid no, it's about sort using 3 different values (1, 0, -1) to sort out the array. When you do `return a > b;` you either return true or false, 1 or 0. Note: It's not really 1 and -1. Positive and Negative is more accurate.

Comment: @MinusFour I believe I see what you are saying now. The Comparison function passed in returns a (`true` or `false`) value as apposed to a (`1`, `0` or `-1`) value. This could cause some wonky behavior? While it works for the test data I have provided, maybe it requires some doctoring before being set free in the wilderness.

Comment: @MinusFour You're right that this implementation of the `sort()` isn't strictly best practice - although it will work fine due to Javascript's loose data types. I'll amend it.